# Converting euros to czk vs converting rands (zar) to czk

Tags: airports, money, exchange

I am traveling to Prague and Berlin at the end of the year. In South Africa we are unable to access the czk currency. I have been told a way is to convert euros to czk upon arrival.

The issue I am having is that I will constantly be needing to convert money as my bank card cash passport only holds euros. And to swipe is ridiculous.

So if anyone can tell me about exchanging the SA currency to czk at an airport or bank is possible, I would really appreciate it. Like if I had to swipe my S.A. credit card at a bank could they provide me with czk.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why is it "ridiculous" to use your bank card? Unless you have a particularly greedy bank, withdrawing local currency from an ATM should convert to the currency of your account automatically, and often at a better rate than cash exchange places will offer.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend getting ahold of those euros, in paper form if possible.

Even if Prague airport accepts SA currency, the rate will make you cry. As a rule of thumb, the further you go from your border and the smaller your country's economy is, the worse is the exchange rate, as growth of spread.

E.g. for Euro you're going to see 25.00 buy ~ 26.50 sell spread, but for SA money 1.0 buy ~ 2.0 sell perhaps.